# Using slice/filter within case_when respecting group_by

Tags: r, dplyr

I want to replace (using dplyr) single values of a column `W` within each group `Group` when it is "unkown" by the value of that column where `Y` has a specific value ("a").

There's not necessarily always an "a" in column `Y` per group. If not the value "unkown" could stay.

That's what I've tried so far and it works if I do it for a single group, but the slice (could also be a filter command) seems not to respect my grouping? Note that some groups don't have an unkown values (no replacement needed), groups are differently large.

```
library(dplyr)

# create example data frame
df <- data.frame(
  Group = c("A", "A","A", "B", "B", "B","C","C", "D"),
  Y = factor(c("a","b", "b", "a","b", "b", "a","b", "a"), levels = c("a", "b")),
  W = c("Lake","unknown",  "River", "Lake", "River", "unknown", "Lake","Lake", "River"),
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)

# use case_when() to replace unknown values
# works for a single filtered group
df %>%
  filter(Group=="A")%>%
  group_by(Group) %>%
  mutate(W = case_when(
    W == "unknown" ~ 
      slice(., which(Y == "a"))$W,
    TRUE ~ W
  )) %>%
  ungroup()

# does not work:
df %>%
  group_by(Group) %>%
  mutate(W = case_when(
    W == "unknown" ~ 
      slice(., which(Y == "a"))$W,
    TRUE ~ W
  )) %>%
  ungroup()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `ifelse`:

```r
df %>% 
  group_by(Group) %>% 
  mutate(W = ifelse(W == "unknown" & any(Y == "a"), W[Y == "a"], W))

  Group Y     W       
1 A     a     Lake   
2 A     b     Lake   
3 A     b     River  
4 B     a     Lake   
5 B     b     River  
6 B     b     Lake   
7 C     a     Lake   
8 C     b     Lake   
9 D     b     unknown
```

---

With a slightly modified data set to show a group with "unknown" but no A:

```r
df <- data.frame(
  Group = c("A", "A","A", "B", "B", "B","C","C", "D"),
  Y = factor(c("a","b", "b", "a","b", "b", "a","b", "b"), levels = c("a", "b")),
  W = c("Lake","unknown",  "River", "Lake", "River", "unknown", "Lake","Lake", "unknown"),
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)
```

Answer (score 2):

Given that you will always have one `a` in your `Y` column per group, then you can try:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
 group_by(Group) %>% 
 mutate(W = replace(W, W == 'unknown', W[Y == 'a']))

# A tibble: 9 × 3
# Groups:   Group [4]
  Group Y     W    
  <chr> <fct> <chr>
1 A     a     Lake 
2 A     b     Lake 
3 A     b     River
4 B     a     Lake 
5 B     b     River
6 B     b     Lake 
7 C     a     Lake 
8 C     b     Lake 
9 D     a     River
```

Comment: There's not necessarily always an "a" in column "Y" per group. Added that info to the initial post

Comment: So if there are 2 `a`s, which one to you replace?